# Equivalence definition of group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

On Dummit and Foote, group is defined to be:

> A group is a pair of $(G, m)$ consisting of a set $G$ and a map $m: G \times G \to G$ such that:
>
> - $\forall g_1, g_2, g_3 \in G, m(g_1, m(g_2, g_3)) = m(m(g_1, g_2), g_3)$ - associative property.
> - $\forall g \in G, \exists e \in G$ such that $m(g,e) = g = m(e,g).$
> - $\forall g \in G$, exists an element $g^{-1} \in G$ such that $m(g, g^{-1}) = e = m(g^{-1},g)$.

So I am wondering, where the closure goes? Is there an equivalence?

Comment: Closure is encoded in the fact that $m$ maps $G\times G$ to $\color{Red}G$. Is that what you mean by "where the closure goes" or "an equivalence"?

Comment: Yes, now I see. Thank you @anon

Answer (score 1):

*This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.*

---

The closure comes from the fact that we assume $m : G \times G \color{red}{\to G}$.